# Google Calendar events created on the phone won't sync

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sync, calendar

In my 2.3.7 Android phone, when I use the Google Calendar application, I can see all the events that are listed in my Google account, as I would see them in the browser in my computer, but when I create a new event using the phone -- it shows as 'PC Sync', the new item won't sync up to the calendar as I see it in the browser. I have tried cleaning the cache and data for the 'Calendar' and 'Calendar Storage' application, and manually re-syncing the Google account from the phone, but it still won't show up. Any ideas?

EDIT: If the event is under 'PC Sync', where should they appear in Google Calendar?

Comment: Can you verify if you are creating the even in proper calendar?

Comment: To clarify roxan's question: your calendar app supports multiple calendars. This includes the Google Calendar, but may also have a "PC Sync", "Exchange", "Phone"... calendar. Only events created in the Google Calendar are synced with the Google Calendar. Are you sure your events were created there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question after the comments, it turns out only 'PC Sync' would show when creating an event by tapping on a specific day/time, but when using the 'Add event' option, the other calendars would show as an option. Once this is used the first time, then tapping on the day/time shows the other options. All good.