# Do not see synchronized "My calendar" on Android 4.1.2 phone in Google Calendar web interface

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar

I have added new event in Gapps "Calendar" application (Google Calendar) on my Android 4.1.2 phone.  This event got added to "My calendar" calendar (and I **cannot change** this which calendar this event belongs to **after creation**).

Though "My calendar" is selected both in *Calendars to display* and *Calendars to sync* it is not visible in Google Calendar web interface: https://www.google.com/calendar/

Where this "My calendar" is sync'ed to?  Can I add it to be visible from web interface (does it have and URL)?  How can I copy or move event to my main personal Google Calendar calendar ("Jakub Narebski <...@gmail.com>")?

---

I see that I [should have added the first event by using Menu > New event](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/30659/43152) rather than clicking on timeline.  How can I copy it to other calendar?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you ever find a solution to this?